# Query new Django/Postgres DateRangeField

Tags: django, postgresql

Suppose I want to have a model like this:

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.postgres.fields import DateRangeField

class QueryRange(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField('Name', max_length=50)
    rsv = DateRangeField()
```

And in shell I create some objects like this:

```
obj1 = QueryRange.objects.create(name='John', rsv=('2016-06-01', '2016-06-10'))
obj2 = QueryRange.objects.create(name='Peter', rsv=('2016-07-05', '2016-07-10'))
obj3 = QueryRange.objects.create(name='Chris', rsv=('2016-07-12', '2016-07-15'))
```

How can I query the db by asking this question: *Please check and see if the date i.e '2016-07-08' is occupied or not*.

Something like this won't work:

```
from psycopg2.extras import DateRange

rng = DateRange('2016-07-08')
QueryRange.objects.filter(rsv__contains=rng)
```

I have implement the same scenario with two separate `date` fields (`from_date` and `until_date`) and works great (of course). I am just curious how can I benefit myself with the `DateRangefield`.

Cheers to all Djangonauts out there!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're very close with your answer. When you're looking for the presence of a single date, use a date object directly:

```
from datetime import date
QueryRange.objects.filter(rsv__contains=date.today())
```

If you're using a date range to query, you're probably looking to see if there's any overlap:

```
rng = DateRange('2016-07-08', '2016-07-20')
QueryRange.objects.filter(rsv__overlap=rng)
```

Tested both examples to make sure they work.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I'll try it asap and post here for results.

Comment: That worked brilliant! But when I search, say, for `QueryRange.objects.filter(rsv__contains=date(2016, 6, 10))` which is the upper bound for John it gives me nothing. I know that by default it is excluded. How can I include it? (Not for `DateRange`, but for `date`)

Comment: Do you mean if you have a date range of `$d1` to `$d2` in your database and you filter for `$d2`, you get no results because it has `[)` bounds? The only solution right now is to search for `$d2 - timedelta(days=1)`. I recently opened a ticket with django to have other bounds like `[]` implemented so this doesn't happen.

Comment: That's exactly what I mean. Please post the ticket ID to keep track of it. Thank you. Cheers!

Comment: [Here you go](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/27147); I plan to work on it over the weekend. But you should know that `[$d1, $d2]` is equal to `[$d1, $d2 + 1)` for discrete types like dates so you can put in a temporary work around like I mentioned above.

Comment: Yes. Thank you for the hint! Best regards

Comment: Hi @nik_m, I have a problem with DateRangeField using form. I hope you can help me with this. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40754888/django-daterangefield-issue