# Django DateRangeField issue

Tags: python, django, postgresql

I have a problem with [DateRangeField](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/contrib/postgres/fields/#daterangefield/) inserting to database using Forms.

**model.py**

```
from django.contrib.postgres.fields import DateRangeField
from django.db import models

class Event(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    datefromto = DateRangeField()
```

**views.py**

```
date_from = '2011-01-01'
date_to = '2011-01-31'
data = {
    "name" : "Test Name",
    "datefromto" : [date_from,date_to ]
}

form = Event_form(data)
if form.is_valid():
    form.save()
else:
    print(form.errors)
```

**forms.py**

```
class Event_form(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Event
        fields = ('name','datefromto')

    def clean(self):
        print(self.cleaned_data)
        #{"name" : "Test Name"} there should be 'datefromto' key
```

When I call the *form.is_valid()* it returns **"datefromto is required"** it shouldn't be like this because there's a 'datefromto' inside the dictionary. When I try to print the cleaned_data in form clean function, it only prints **{"name" : "Test Name"}** without the *datefromto* key.

---

Django 1.9,Python 2.7 and Postgre 9.3.14.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After digging into the django source code, you should append `number suffix` for range field like that:

```
date_from = '2011-01-01'
date_to = '2011-01-31'
data = {
    "name" : "Test Name",
    "datefromto_0" : date_from,
    "datefromto_1" : date_to
}

form = Event_form(data)
if form.is_valid():
    form.save()
else:
    print(form.errors)
```

I have used `pdb` to trace the code inside django, and found this trick...

And when you get stuck with other the issues in django next time, you can make use of `pdb` to trace. it is really a great tool for python debugging...

hope it would help... :).

Comment: It works like a charm! Thanks @Enix. Gonna check that pdb guy soon.

Comment: +1 from me. Very nice answer and works likes a charm, indeed! May I ask @Enix where in the source code did you find the need for the `number suffix`?

Comment: @nik_m you can follow the execution path of `is_valid`, and then you will find that it calls `MultiWidget.value_from_datadict` in `django/forms/widgets.py`.  Inside this method, it will use the field `name` suffixing with enumerating index `i` to generate a key to pull value from `data` dict. need a little bit concentration to find this line indeed...

Comment: Cool! Thank you very much!

Comment: They should include this in official documentation. I can't really find it anywhere.

Comment: @Enix bro. I have similar problem. How can I insert ArrayField using forms?

Comment: @aldesabido you can save the model like this: `f=Event_form(data={'name':'12', 'datefromto_0':'2016-12-01', 'datefromto_1':'2016-12-31'}); f.save()`

Comment: This is hands down the best answer on this topic, and I have searched. The Django documentation on DateRange is terrible imo, you have a simple working solution

Comment: If you look at source code of the rendered template by admin.py, you can see the fieldname with appended _0 _1.